# How to approach to this design - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

My App is Navigation based Application for iPad.

First Screen is Home Screen. On Clicking button on Home Screen, it pushes to Map Screen. On the Map Screen, i have left Panel (view controller) over the map view controller which occupies 1/4 of the screen.

Left Panel is a View Controller which has Table View. On clicking cell, it should push new viewcontroller to left panel leaving the map view controller behind.

```
             Push
Home Screen -------- Map Screen
                  |(Added over map screen)         Push
                  |----- Left Panel (Table View) -------- Detail View
```

I can't use Split View Controller because there is a navigation in left panel as well as in Home Screen. Some times i need to animate/hide left panel. I can customise left panel.

How to implement this structure. Is it good to use Nested Navigation Controller or is there any library available. My App supports both Portrait and Landscape. I am using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't know Swift as well. However, I think you have to declare a base layout:
you will have a MainViewController that will include a `LeftPanelViewController` and a `FrontViewController`. In the MainViewController nib, you will create the main layout using `AutoLayout`: add a UIView at the left of the screen and another UIView for the frontpage.
Then, link outlets and you will have the layout done! Then you have only to add/remove subviews to `leftPanelView` and to `FrontView`.

Now, I think that the right logic is that `MainViewController` is the `NavigationController`, so you have to implement the protocol of `LeftPanelViewController` and `FrontViewController`, so Main will know how and when add/remove subviews.

The important things is that no one object have to know the existence of `MainViewController` to preserve the logic. So you have to notify `MainViewController` for something, to use `delegation pattern` or something else as `NSNotification` (be aware, it could be much weight...)

I hope it will bel helpful. Bye

Comment: Thanks. But i think i have to manually handle push and pop animations in left panel view.

Comment: I think that a `UINavigationController` inside a `UIView` subview of the `MainViewController` is not good. Maybe is better if you implement a custom method to add/remove subviews with a sort of animation.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by adding a `ContainerView` as your Left Panel. As you want to do pushes here, you can make the container view controller a navigation controller with the table view as its root view controller.

You'll still be able to animate/hide the container view just like any other view.

Answer (score 0):

This extension for the UIViewController creates the side panel to the left.

```
private var temp_view:UIView?
private var temp_width:CGFloat?
private weak var temp_sidebar:UIViewController?

 extension UIViewController {



func configureSideBar(StoryBoard:String,SideBarIdentifier:String,View:UIView){

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoard, bundle: nil)
    weak var sidebar = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SideBarIdentifier) as? UIViewController
    let width:CGFloat = 250//sidebar!.view.frame.size.width
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)

    temp_view = View
    temp_width = width
    temp_sidebar = sidebar

    sidebar!.view.frame = frame
    addChildViewController(sidebar!)
    view.addSubview(sidebar!.view)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(sidebar!.view)
    toogleSideBarWithAnimation(0.2,Open:false)

}


func getSidebar() -> UIViewController?{

    if let sdbar = temp_sidebar {
        return sdbar
    }
    else {
       println("Warning:You have tou configure sidebar first")
        return nil
    }

}


func toogleSideBarWithAnimation(Duration:NSTimeInterval,Open:Bool) {

    if let view = temp_view {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(Duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            var Frame = view.frame

            if !Open{

                Frame.origin.x = 0
            }
            else {
                Frame.origin.x = temp_width!
            }

            view.frame = Frame
            }, completion: { finished in

        })
    }
    else {
        println("Warning:You have tou configure sidebar first")

    }
}
```

}

Let me explain how to use it.

First create a view controller scene and set the storyboard id. In this examples i used "sidebar"
Then add this instruction to the map view controller to the viewDidLoad like this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.configureSideBar("Main", SideBarIdentifier: "sidebar", View: Subview)
}
```

I suggest adding a UIView with all your view in it in the map view controller

To open and close it use this instruction

```
self.toogleSideBarWithAnimation(0.2,Open:OpenSidebar)
```